# Pod error after adding audioplayer package to Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, audio-player, pod-install

I'm following a tutorial for Flutter, which uses the audioplayer package. Unfortunately, when I try to run the project after adding the package, it doesn't work anymore... I tried everything I found around, but nothing seems to work: I get errors like

"Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13."

I tried to uninstall cocoapods, reinstall pod, but every time I get a lot of errors... I don't know what to do anymore...
[this is an example of what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evDtB.jpg)

Edit: after doing "cd ios" and "pod deintegrate", when I do "pod install" [I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmQOa.jpg).  [This is the beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X6Lp.jpg)

Comment: Might be wrong but the error is located above, in the console output you shared on your screens. The `Error launching application on iPhone 13` is just a cascade effect of pod install failing. However we cannot see what the actual error looks like. Try scrolling back up to the begining of the stacktrace

Comment: I just added it

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps in your terminal:

1. `cd ios`
2. `pod deintegrate`
3. `pod install`
4. `cd ..`
5. `flutter pub get`

Then try running again.

Comment: I got the error I posted above at step 3

Comment: Hm..Please scroll up to the beginning of the error and add it to your question.

Comment: I just added it